# running official example of angular calendar

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fullcalendar

I am trying to run official example of angular-calendar component: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/

However, I am getting error: *TypeError: undefined is not a function* - apparently function **scope.calendar.fullCalendar** is undefined

here are my JS files that I include:

```
<script src="../public/components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="../public/components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<script src="../public/components/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../public/components/jquery-ui/ui/minified/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="../public/components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../public/components/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js"></script>
<script src="../public/components/fullcalendar/gcal.js"></script>
<script src="../public/components/angular-ui-calendar/src/calendar.js"></script>
<script src="../public/components/fullcalendar/gcal.js"></script>
```

Could you help me find the problem?

Comment: jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/F2jLL/1/

Answer (score 8):

Load jQuery *before* angular (and fullcalendar *after* jquery) :

```
<!-- First jQuery -->
<script src="../public/components/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../public/components/jquery-ui/ui/minified/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<!-- then angular -->
<script src="../public/components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="../public/components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<script src="../public/components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- fullcalendar -->
<script src="../public/components/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js"></script>
<script src="../public/components/fullcalendar/gcal.js"></script>

<!-- angular-ui-calendar -->
<script src="../public/components/angular-ui-calendar/src/calendar.js"></script>
```